# ALLOY - How to set value for a signature

Tags: function, signature, alloy

I want to formalize an access from an application to the data section of other application. Firstly, I create signatures for Request (e.g APP1 wants to READ the DATASECTION of APP2) and Permission (the request A is MAY_PREVENT)

```
sig request{
 from: OS_App,
 to: Memory,
 act: action
}

sig permission{
    req: request,
    per: status
}
```

I wrote two functions for my idea, but it does not work. Someone can help me, please?

```
//Assign a request 
pred P_026 [asc: request, app1: NonTrusted, app2: OS_App, ds: app2.ownDS]{
    asc.from = app1
    asc.to = ds
    asc.act = read
}

//If the Request is A then status is may_prevent
fun F_026[s: status, requ: request, app1: NonTrusted, app2: OS_App, ds: app2.ownDS]: set may_prevent{
    {s : requ.per | requ in P_026[requ,app1,app2,ds]} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still struggling with this problem !! I don't understand completely your problem since we don't see the definition of all the signatures : "NonTrusted", "action" ...

But I can see that there is a problem here : "requ in P_026[requ,app1,app2,ds]" you can not write this " an atom in a predicate" is absurde..

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I solved this problem :D

Comment: @TrìnhLêKhánh Great !!